# Notepad++ stopped color-coding my source code... How to fix?

Tags: ide, notepad++

For no apparent reason, it just stopped. No more color-coding. Is there a mystery setting I accidentally turned off?

Comment: It stopped completely, for every file? Or just for a certain file? Did it previously work with that file (under its current name)?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same problem and discovered it was because I had enabled global foreground color under Global Styles.

Answer (score 15):

Try out the following:

1. Select a language manually from the "Languages" menu.
2. In Settings/Preferences, check the File Associatons.
3. In worst case, reinstall.

Comment: This advise only true if you tried the accepted answer without success.

Answer (score 10):

In the **Language** menu select your corresponding language. For example **H** and then **html**

Comment: That fixed it for me! The global settings wasn't the issue. Thanks Todd

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was to go into the Style Configurator, select the 'Global Styles' from the Language selection box and uncheck the 'Enable global foreground colour' option. I am not sure why that was checked, but all of the code coloring worked after unchecking it. Thanks Richard!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look in Settings -> Style Configurator. Maybe your styles got messed up somehow. You could try changing the selected style to see if it makes a difference.

I think the saved styles are stored in the "themes" directory under your Notepad++ installation directory, so you could also check that the files have not become corrupted in some way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (I Googled "notepad++ file coloring quit" to find this discussion.) In my case the coloring quit mid file in a single file. I finally realized that adjacent string literals with one of them a macro was fooling Notepad++.
My code that broke it read:
    Write_Supplemental_Configuration(privateData->new_config, FTP_ROOT_DIR"/lists.csv");
and the fix was to add a space after the macro:
    Write_Supplemental_Configuration(privateData->new_config, FTP_ROOT_DIR "/lists.csv");

I tried replacing the macro FTP_ROOT_DIR with "foo" and the problem went away.

So in my case it was a macro that fooled the Notepad++ coloring.

Comment: This has happened to me quite often while editing extremely large files or when scrolling rapidly through files.  It seems that the highlighting doesn't keep up at times.

Answer (score 2):

watch out for the single quote that you copy from the web. if you get one of those "upper commas" instead of the tic mark it will confuse the code and kill the coloring (in SQL).  just delete and replace.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you save the file it's saved as an **.html** instead of a **.txt**. This make a difference because the **.html** allows you to see the different colour codes whereas **.txt** doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check, if you have saved the documents as .HTML and not as .txt
2. in the menu, choose Settings>Style configurator...
   and in the list in the left pan select html, check if the colors for different tags are being shown in the color blocks. if yes, chosse a font and then save and exit.
3. Check only after you save the document in .html, whether it is working or not.

Comment: This answer is very similar to some of the older answers. When answering an old question you need to add significant extra information, just writing the same as an existing answer is not helpful. Such answers are likely to be poorly received.

Answer (score 1):

The language setting solved the issue for (all) 3 Javascript files (.js) which suffered from it, which previously were all recognized correctly as Javascript. For some reason it forgot they were Javascript files apparently!?

Answer (score 1):

First type any thing and Save the file in any format you are working with (i-e; .cpp if c++, .js if JavaScript....etc)

And make sure global foreground color is disabled.

And it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

File > Save As > Format Type = Structured Query Language > Name the file with '*.sql'. THIS SHOULD BRING ALL THE COLOR CODES.....to differentiate your code and make it look pretty. J

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display text in SQL format, then in menu select Language => S => SQL

Comment: Welcome to SO, this does not provide an answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same thing happen to me. The only way I could fix it was to rename the file (I just added one character). Then open it with notepad++. The code was colored again. Then renamed the file back to the original name and it is still colored.

I have since found that if I close Notepad++ without closing the file first this happens. Try closing the file first then close Notepad++ then reopen the file.

This bug seems to be fixed as of version 7.8.6

Answer (score 1):

Got to Setting -> Style Configuration and remove the global style checkbox

[image: Setting]

Comment: The instructions are correct, but your picture shows something different: it shows Settings -> Preferences instead of Settings -> Style Configurator.

Answer (score 0):

If the coloring only stopped working for one file, you should check the extension name of your file.  You might have accidentally saved the file as .txt

Answer (score 0):

A couple years late here, but I'm pretty sure you're opening ".txt" files that contain your source code. Because the file doesn't have the language's extension, Notepad++ can't determine how to color-code it. You'll have to select the language under the "Language" tab.